# can not pass IQueryable<T> to GridModel constructor of telerik Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

In the [help page of telerik grid control](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-data-binding-server-binding.html), it's said that we can pass IQueryable to GridModel constructor, but I see no overload constructor that accept IQueryable paramenter. There are only 3 overload constructor for DataTable, IEnumerable, and default constructor with no param.

Anybody help me, thanks!
PS: I'm using the lastest telerik library 2012.1.214, version of MVC 1.

> Telerik Grid for ASP.NET MVC is using its build-in Linq expression
>   engine. This means that you don't need to care for paging, sorting and
>   filtering the data. You only need to provide an IQueryable and the
>   grid will do the rest pushing the paging, sorting and filtering
>   expressions to the underlying IQueryable provider. The provider is
>   responsible for executing those expressions to the database server.

Comment: IQueryable is almost the same as IEnumerable. Perhaps a small parsing would suffice? (http://forums.asp.net/t/1257200.aspx/1)

Comment: I use IQueryable in the constructor of the GridModel and it works perfectly. When you set IQueryable to a parameter that want to receive IEnumerable, you will don't have any design time error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you should use the constructor which takes only `IEnumerable` is due to the fact that its the parent of `IQueryable`.

As I see it , its an inheritance issue.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.iqueryable.aspx